# Rounding to the nearest multiple of a given value

Tags: c, math

If we have an arbitrary `double` value `f`, another one `v` and a multiplication factor `p`, how can I snap the value `f` to the nearest `v` power of `p`?

Example:

- f = 3150.0
- v = 100.0
- p = 2

the multiplications will go like this

- 100 (`v`)
- 200 (multiplied by `p`)
- 400
- 800
- 1600
- 3200

...

`f` is closest to `3200.0` so the function should return `3200.0`

There was actually a name for this, which I seem to have forgotten and maybe this is why I couldn't find such a function.

Comment: Does "*nearest*" mean absolute difference, or ratio? `log_p(f/v)` should give you an idea where to look.

Comment: @dxiv The value should be snapped to the nearest multiplication. In the example that is one of the values listed (if value <= 3200)

Comment: Round `log_p(f/v)` to the nearest integer `k`, then the number you are looking for is `p^k v`. If that's not what you are after, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66328250/edit) the question and clarify.

Comment: @dxiv What is `log_p` though? If that's a function name, there is no such in C. Or is it log above p

Comment: The [logarithm to base p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm). You can calculate `log_p(f/v)` as `log(f/v) / log(p)`.

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry I am nowhere to be found in math :)

Comment: I think this works :) Yes yes, I quickly realized I forgot to use `round`, my bad

Comment: Yes it does, why not posting as an answer? This is to be used to snap a fine-grained zoom value to a multiple of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `k = floor(log_p(f/v))` where `log_p(x) = log(x)/log(p)` is the logarithm to base `p` function. It follows from the properties of `floor` and `log` that `p^k v <= f < p^(k+1) v`, which gives the two closest values to `f` of the form `p^n v`.

Which of those two values to choose depends on the exact definition of "*nearest*" in your use-case. If taken in the multiplicative sense (as would be natural on a log scale), that "*nearest*" value can be calculated directly as `p^n v` where `n = round(log_p(f/v)) = round(log(f/v)/log(p))`.

Comment: You are so good at math. I need to learn all this too. Also, what do you think about editing my question applying appropriate terminology, to make it easier to find and to understand from others? If you think it is useful so that others can find my question and your answer.

Comment: @Edenia The question is well enough written, except you made a typo at "*power of two*" instead of "*power of `p`*". The worked-out example also helps, and the remaining ambiguity is about how "*nearest*" is defined, which I can't second-guess. For example, `4` is closer to `2` than `8` in a linear sense (since `4-2 < 8-4`), but is equally close to `2` and `8` in a multiplicative sense (since `4/2 = 8/4`).

Comment: So I should add nearest (in the linear sense).

Comment: Or "*nearest (in the sense of minimum distance)*", which may be easier to understand. However, in that case the solution is not given by `round`, but instead by one of `floor` or `ceil` which has to be chosen by comparing the two distances `f - p^k v` with `p^(k+1) v - f`.

Comment: The correct solution seems to be just with `round`

Comment: @Edenia `f=23`, `v=2`, `p=2` will give `32` using `round`, and indeed `32/23 = 1.39 < 1.44 = 23/16` so `23` is closer to `32` in the multiplicative sense. But `23-16 = 7 < 9 = 32-23`, so `23` is closer to `16` in the sense of absolute distance.

Comment: Yes, as you said it is a matter of the use case. Though, for my own it turns out that I'll have to create `roundUP` and `roundDown` functions instead of nearest (otherwise zooming in can result in zooming out and the opposite)